# spring-cloud-starter-config POST /env not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I have a little spring boot web application (executable jar) which has some custom properties inside the application.properties file. 
My goal is to be able to dynamically alter these properties at runtime without having to run a build/deploy or restarting the java process. 
The spring-cloud-starter-config project seems to be well suited for this (even though I am not using a config server) but I ran into the following problem:

In my pom.xml I include dependencies to spring-boot-starter-actuator and spring-cloud-starter-config. 
The application.properties configures below properties

```
management.port=8081
management.context-path=/management
management.security.enabled=false
foo=bar
```

I can read the variables using

```
curl http://localhost:8081/management/env/foo
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Below update seems to succeed as well

```
curl -X POST -d foo=foo http://localhost:8081/management/env
{"foo":"foo"}
```

When I query the whole env I see the changed value in the manager section and the original value inside applicationConfig

```
curl http://localhost:8081/management/env
{
  ...
  "manager": {
    "foo": "foo"
  },
  ...
  "configServerClient": {
    "spring.cloud.config.enabled": "false"
  },
  ...
  "applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]": {
  ...
  "foo": "bar",
  ...
  }
}
```

Now when I query the variable again I still get the old value

```
curl http://localhost:8081/management/env/foo
{"foo":"bar"}
```

This is contrary to what I read on some web blogs. In my understanding the changed value should show up. 
What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to dynamically change values in the application.properties without restarting the server?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

You need to run refresh after posting changes to env

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/management/refresh
```

Comment: Since no one has commented, this worked for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a spring boot version greater than 2.2.4, then you have to manually enable the POST API call using the below the property.

> management.endpoint.env.post.enabled=true

Answer (score 2):

for me it only works with

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"foo", "value":"bar"}' http://localhost:8081/management/env/
```

otherwise I get

```
"Missing parameters: value,name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set `management.security.enabled:false` to allow sending POST requests to `/env` endpoint.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.