# spring-cloud how to use Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

[management endpoints:](https://bushkarl.gitbooks.io/spring-cloud/content/cloud_native_applications/spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html)

For a Spring Boot Actuator application there are some additional management endpoints:

```
    POST to /env to update the Environment and rebind @ConfigurationProperties and log levels
```

http://localhost:8080/env/testprop it works and returns:

```
{
"testprop": "test value"
}
```

but when I do POST: http://localhost:8080/env/testprop
Request method 'POST' not supported

I want to update `testprop`, how to do it with API?

Comment: have you tried to post the JSON you showed us against /env ?
I don't know for sure how it works, but if i would implement it I either would allow post against /env or a put against /env/$propertyName

Comment: Yes, I tried it but maybe I did something wrong
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962897/spring-cloud-starter-config-post-env-not-working

Comment: I thin the mistake in the question you linked is that he posted against /management/env and not /env. If posting against /env does not work for you i need a minimal example that reproduces this so i can have a quick look at it.

Comment: when I call POST on http://localhost:8080/env/ I get: Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Interesting, could you please provide a minimal sample of your application? I would like to have a look at it :)

Comment: Just create empty project with spring cloud and actuator at https://start.spring.io/ . Turn off security  in application.properties management.security.enabled=false

Answer (score 1):

I found the following in the [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_endpoints)

> For a Spring Boot Actuator application there are some additional management endpoints:
>
> - POST to /env to update the Environment and rebind @ConfigurationProperties and log levels
> - /refresh for re-loading the boot strap context and refreshing the @RefreshScope beans
> - /restart for closing the ApplicationContext and restarting it (disabled by default)
> - /pause and /resume for calling the Lifecycle methods (stop() and start() on the ApplicationContext)

Looks like you have to post agains /env instead of /end/$yourProperty

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works:
 must POST with empty body 
http://localhost:8080/env/?test=dasda
and response is:

```
{
    "test": "dasda"
}
```